# How does bit.ly allow anyone to use cname.bit.ly as their CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

To use bit.ly pro, you need to make a CNAME entry pointing to cname.bit.ly

How does cname.bit.ly have to be configured in order to let this happen?

**Updated for a more detailed explanation.**

a.domain.com points to c.b.com
a.domain.com simply needs a CNAME entry.
c.b.com needs to actually serve the request. How should this server be configured to allow this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parallel research, I found that a simple `<VirtualHost *:80>` in the `.conf` file suffices.

It was never about serving different content based on domain name. It's about serving the same content regardless of domain name (which I have no control over), hopefully without having to do something special for every new third party domain name that wants to point to mine.

Answer (score 3):

The domain name doesn't need any particular configuration -- anyone can create a CNAME for any domain they own, pointing to any other domain name.

The server will presumably need to be configured to do the short URL expansion for bit.ly Pro paying customers, and block all other domain names that may be CNAMEd to cname.bit.ly by non-customers.

Comment: ok, but what server configuration allows for the server to let this happen?

Comment: It's not a simple server configuration; it's probably some proprietary software. You need to write software that will pick up the http Host: request header and then take whatever action you want depending on the value of that header.

Comment: If what you want is simply to serve different content based on the hostname used to connect, then the mention of bit.ly was a bit of a misdirection. You need to do some research on Name Based Virtual Hosts.